# cyrillic font problem in android

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, truetype

I gave a somewhat simple problem. I have a .ttf font with Cyrillic Unicode support (Macedonian) but when i use it in my application only the Latin characters are in the font and the Cyrillic stay the default android font. Any help or some kind of a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, the font was corrupted!